# auto populate data from one list to another list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

**Basically i want to add items to 1 list based on columns from another list. so for example say i have 2 list, List 1 and List 2. List 1 has 3 colunms; Name, Address, Manager. List 2 contains 3 colums; Name, Address, Manager.

What i want to do is when an item is added to list 1 i want to automatically add a new item to list 2. List 2 colunms should be autopopulated by the colunm values from list 1.
I tried Using a workflow but it is not working. any one know?**

Answer (score 1):

Why it didn't work with workflows? Did you make sure that the workflow is running on item created on List1? Did you make sure you're not testing the workflow with System Account? If you've seen the workflow "In Progress", did it throw any errors?

Comment: I tried but it is not working am new for sharepoint ,If u know the process pls send.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.lynda.com/SharePoint-tutorials/Creating-new-list-item/144025/161251-4.html , use SharePoint Designer to do so, and use the Create List Item action to create the item in List2 with values of item in List1